# Why are autoload, load_all! and require all used in active_support.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload, activesupport

I was looking at `active_support.rb` to try to understand the load process it uses. It uses three loading methods: `load_all!`, `autoload` and `require`. 
Why use three different ways of loading in the same file?

```
module ActiveSupport
  def self.load_all!
    [Dependencies, Deprecation, Gzip, MessageVerifier, Multibyte, SecureRandom, TimeWithZone]
  end

  autoload :BacktraceCleaner, 'active_support/backtrace_cleaner'
  autoload :Base64, 'active_support/base64'
  autoload :BasicObject, 'active_support/basic_object'
  autoload :BufferedLogger, 'active_support/buffered_logger'
  autoload :Cache, 'active_support/cache'
  autoload :Callbacks, 'active_support/callbacks'
  autoload :Deprecation, 'active_support/deprecation'
  autoload :Duration, 'active_support/duration'
  autoload :Gzip, 'active_support/gzip'
  autoload :Inflector, 'active_support/inflector'
  autoload :Memoizable, 'active_support/memoizable'
  autoload :MessageEncryptor, 'active_support/message_encryptor'
  autoload :MessageVerifier, 'active_support/message_verifier'
  autoload :Multibyte, 'active_support/multibyte'
  autoload :OptionMerger, 'active_support/option_merger'
  autoload :OrderedHash, 'active_support/ordered_hash'
  autoload :OrderedOptions, 'active_support/ordered_options'
  autoload :Rescuable, 'active_support/rescuable'
  autoload :SecureRandom, 'active_support/secure_random'
  autoload :StringInquirer, 'active_support/string_inquirer'
  autoload :TimeWithZone, 'active_support/time_with_zone'
  autoload :TimeZone, 'active_support/values/time_zone'
  autoload :XmlMini, 'active_support/xml_mini'
end

require 'active_support/vendor'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
require 'active_support/dependencies'
require 'active_support/json'

I18n.load_path << "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/active_support/locale/en.yml"
```

Answer (score 16):

I don't know exactly why Rails uses three different loading methods (actually two - see below). But I know, in general, why someone might.

`Require` means "load this right now". `autoload` means "load this when you need to use it". The usual reason to use both is that you have some files that you pretty much assume will be used in every program invocation; and others that are optional. For example, in a Rails application that uses no deprecated methods, you'll never need `Deprecation`; so why slow down the initial setup by loading that file?

In other cases, you might distinguish between files that will be needed early in the program's execution, and files that can wait. For example, you're not likely to need `Gzip` until the first request comes in. So by using autoload, you can trim some time off the initial setup, at the cost of a slight slowdown for the first request.

You might ask, well, why not just use `autoload` for everything? Why load *anything* before it's absolutely needed? One reason is that autoload only works for constants. So, for example, `active_support/core_ext` adds a bunch of methods to Numeric so you can write code like `3.days`, `6.minutes`, and `16.seconds.ago`. There's no constant in `3.days`, so you can't trigger an autoload on that expression. (And you can't autoload `Numeric`, because the base class has already been loaded - it's just the extensions you want to add.)

Finally, this class doesn't actually use three loading methods; it uses two, and provides one (sort of). `load_all!` is used by `Rails::Initializer` to

> ```
> # Preload all frameworks specified by the Configuration#frameworks.
> # Used by Passenger to ensure everything's loaded before forking and
> # to avoid autoload race conditions in JRuby.
> ```

I don't know the details, and I don't know why these specific modules are preloaded (and not the others). But since this is meant to support specific environments, you can see why it might require code separate from the default loading mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The `autoload` ruby method can be used to associate a constant with a filename that will be loaded the first time you reference said constant. This keeps you from having to load the entire framework at startup.

It looks like the `load_all!` method is called from the rails `initializer.rb`, and is utilized to preload all of the frameworks that are configured to be pre-loaded.  This works by calling each frameworks `load_all!` method, which is simply references an array of constants... which will trigger the autoload.

According to the comments in `initializer.rb` for `preload_frameworks`...

```
# Preload all frameworks specified by the Configuration#frameworks.
# Used by Passenger to ensure everything's loaded before forking and
# to avoid autoload race conditions in JRuby.
```

The `require` is to load the core required files for the particular framework.